# Angular ui Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using angular  DateTime Picker. i am using $uibModel to show a pop up and couple of fields are there for updatind data. I am using
[**bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker**](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker)
this date to add atetime picker. I am passing JSON and I am displaying in corresponding fields. My date format is

> 2016-02-19T10:55:33+00:00

and My format I am using in input field is

> datetime-picker="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:sssZ"

as per the docs. But I am not getting the model reflected in the text box. If I remove the format in input field I get the model displayed there. Why is this happening? i have given the same format as the value to format input. Thanks.

Comment: can you please add some code here

Comment: Please provide code to accompany your question.

Comment: <input 
name="eventdate" 
type="text"
class="form-control" 
ng-click="vms.openCalendar($event, 'events')"
datetime-picker="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:sssZ"  
ng-model="vms.events.date" 
is-open="vms.events.open">

vms.openCalendar = function(e, picker) {
                        vms[picker].open = true;
                    };